# customize toast in android

Tags: android

Iam trying to changebackground and text color of toast in my application using

```
LayoutInflater infator = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout =infator.inflate(R.layout.toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));
            TextView toastText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toasttext);
            toastText.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            toastText.setText("uei:"+o.getUei());
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
```

This code is present in OnItemClickListener of my listview.

But the application gets force closed with null pointer exception!!

this is what abve the onclick listener, which could give a better picture.

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarms);
        m_alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(this, R.layout.severity_item, m_alarms);
        setListAdapter(m_alarmAdapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "clicked: " + view);
                final Alarm o = m_alarmAdapter.getItem(position);
                LayoutInflater infator = getLayoutInflater();
```

Comment: Brief error report in LogCat 08-25 13:25:14.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2879): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 13:25:14.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2879):     at com.opennms.android.AlarmActivity$2.onItemClick(AlarmActivity.java:65)

Comment: Have you called `setContentView` before `findViewById`?

Comment: @Zeisss line 65 is toastText.setBackgroundcolor... @MByD I set the content view of other alarm.xml file immediately in `onCreate()` method

Comment: @technocrat: Then toastText is null, thus findViewById() returns null, so the `toasttext` seems to be not part of your content view.

Comment: @Zeisss yah it looks so but, i have specified textview with id toasttext in toast.xml.Also  iam using inflator to get the toast.xml. What could be the solution to it then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking your current view to look for the `toasttext` id, not the View you just loaded. Try `layout.findViewById()`