# how can I design custom toast message?

Tags: android, toast

i want custom designed **toast** message in my project, i want custom **toast** with background color and image in **toast** message.
i have seen this type of toast message in many android application. i want to implement this type of toast in my application.

i follow this link : [customize toast in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186884/customize-toast-in-android)

e.g.

[image]

Comment: [http://www.androidinterview.com/android-toast-creating-a-android-custom-toast-example/](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-toast-creating-a-android-custom-toast-example/)

Comment: So? what are the difficulties you met?

Comment: [Heads Up, Updates to toasts in Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61608646/4694013)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can show [custom toast](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-custom-toast-notification/).

All you need to do is: create custom xml for toast.

Something like:

**my_toast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/cyan">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_img"
        android:id="@+id/imageview">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="My message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in your activity, instead of default Toast, inflate this custom xml.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mylayout));

Toast custToast = new Toast(this);
custToast.setView(view);
custToast.show();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: setView method is deprecated in API level  R.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply by creating a layout for toast in xml

layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#DAAA">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toast_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/toast_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

</LinearLayout
```

to inflate and setup the custome toast:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom,
                                                       (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
                        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
//put your image in the drawable folder
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.username_incorrect);
                        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
                        text.setText("The user name is incorect!");

                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();
```

>